# For what value of $c$ is $f$ periodic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, trigonometry

Let $f(x)=a\sin(cx)+b\cos(cx)$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants.

Since $\sin$ and $\cos$ have a period of $2\pi$, if $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $f$ has a period of $2\pi$. How to prove the converse? In other words, how to prove that if $f$ has a period of $2\pi$ then $c\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Well, if $f$ has a period of $2\pi$ then
$$a\sin(cx)+b\cos(cx)=f(x)=f(x+2k\pi)=a\sin(cx+2kc\pi)+b\cos(cx+2kc\pi)$$
for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Probably, to get the result we need some suitable identity. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki "period" is not the same thing as "minimal period".

Comment: ok , set $\tan\theta=\frac{b}{a}$ then $$f(x)=a\sec\theta\,\sin\left(cx+\theta\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $a\cdot b\cdot c \neq 0$, otherwise it is trivial. Thus we can rewrite the expression as it follows:
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = a\sin(cx) + b\cos(cx) = \frac{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}[a\sin(cx) + b\cos(cx)]\\
& = \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\left[\frac{a\sin(cx)}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}} + \frac{b\cos(cx)}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\right] = r\cdot[\cos(\theta)\sin(cx) + \sin(\theta)\cos(cx)]\\
& = r\cdot \sin(cx + \theta),\,\,\text{where}\,\,r = \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}},\,\,\cos(\theta) = \frac{a}{r}\,\,\text{and}\,\,\sin(\theta) = \frac{b}{r}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=a\sin(cx)+b\cos(cx)$$ Suppose $f(x)$ admits a period (not necessarily a minimal one) $2\pi$.

We have then $$f(2\pi)=f(4\pi)\iff a\sin(2c\pi)+b\cos(2c\pi)=a\sin(4c\pi)+b\cos(4c\pi)$$ Let $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\cos (\alpha)=\frac ar$ so $\sin (\alpha)=\frac br$ ($ab\ne0$ of course, as well as $c\ne0$).

It follows $$f(2\pi)=r[\cos (\alpha)\sin (2c\pi)+\sin (\alpha)\cos(2c\pi)]=r\sin(2c\pi+\alpha)\\f(4\pi)=r [cos (\alpha)\sin (4c\pi)+\sin (\alpha)\cos(4c\pi)]=r\sin(4c\pi+\alpha)$$
Hence $$\sin(2c\pi+\alpha)=\sin(4c\pi+\alpha)\Rightarrow 4c\pi+\alpha= 2c\pi+\alpha+2n\pi$$ Thus $$c=n\in \mathbb Z$$